# Integration of exponential and square root function

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I need to solve this $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{ixn}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\,dx,$$ 
where $i^2=-1$ and $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Could you share with us what you already tried ?

Comment: You say that $i$ is $\iota$, not the imaginary unit?

Comment: @fromGiants The imaginary unit *is* iota, according to some authors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Alternative_notations

Comment: Oh, thanks for sharing that. That is actually the first time I've ever heard someone call it that.

Comment: @fromGiants It's not common. But I think it's still mentioned in (at least some) Indian textbooks as iota when it is first introduced. I have seen this myself, and though I call it *i*, some of my students call it "iota" every time (which is quite annoying to hear repeatedly, unlike the monosyllabic alpha, beta, theta, etc.).

Comment: Note that we have,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac {\exp(inx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac {\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac {\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$

Now the real part becomes $0$. so you have only to evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac {\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$ which is equal to $\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac {\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$.

Comment: @WilliamHilbert You got that backwards. It's the imaginary part that becomes zero.

Comment: @DavidH: Oh my, sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is not complete yet.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac {\exp(inx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac {\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx+i \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac {\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac {\cos(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=2I$$

Set $x=a \sinh y$ then $dx=(a \cosh y) dy$ and $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}=a \cosh y$. Let $\pi=a \sinh y_0$.
Then the integration $I$ becomes:
$$I =\int_{0}^{y_0}\cos(n a \sinh y)dy$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=K_0\big(|a|\big)$, where **K** is a [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). Letting $x=nt$, we

have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(nt)}{\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt=K_0\big(|an|\big)$. Unfortunately, there are no “incomplete” Bessel functions,

so your integral does not possess a closed from even in terms of such special expressions, unless, of

course, $n=0$, in which case the answer is simply $\text{arcsinh}\dfrac\pi{|a|}$ . As an aside, for positive values of *a*

and *n*, we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=\frac\pi2\Big[I_0(an)-L_0(an)\Big]$, where ***I*** is another Bessel function,

and ***L*** is a [Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).