# Integration help containing exp and square root

Tags: integration

Integrate this
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
Here $a$ is a constant.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: You have already asked this problem recently:
[IBP for exponential and square root function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/849218/123277). Please don't ask the same question again just because the old one has no answer.

Comment: You may refer to the incomplete answer [here][1].

[1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849218/integration-by-parts-for-exponential-and-square-root-function/855175#855175